# automatic memory mapping with joblib still hits int overflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, joblib

I'm doing some modeling of a neural sensory system, which has different model components for different stages of the system.  Each stage's computations are done in parallel, and then passed to the next stage.

I'm running into `multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<periphery_configuration.PeripheryOutput object at 0x10d00cf28>]'. Reason: 'error("'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647",)'`, which per [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue17560) i believe to mean that I am trying to pass a list of numpy arrays that is so large that `multiprocessing` is running out of index room.

I have attempted to fix this using `joblib`, as follows.  What am I doing wrong?   Per their docs, I should be memoizing to disk automatically; that doesn't appear to be happening.

Here's an abbreviated implementation.  The call to `has_shareable_memory` is some ugly shotgun debugging, and I don't fully understand what it's supposed to do.

The following code works when `self.stimulus` contains less than about 10,000 elements.  It fails with the above error for very long `self.stimulus` on the line `results = Parallel...` in `run`.   `self.solve_one_cochlea` is the method that computes one result.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from joblib.pool import has_shareable_memory
from periphery_model import CochleaModel

class Periphery: 
    def init():
        self.cochlear_list= [[CochleaModel(), self.stimulus[i], self.irr_on[i], i, (0, i + 1)] for i in range(len(self.stimulus))]

    def run(self) -> [PeripheryOutput]:
            """Simulate sound propagation up to the auditory nerve for many stimulus levels
            :return: A list of output data, one for each stimulus level
            """
            s1 = datetime.now()
            results = Parallel(n_jobs=mp.cpu_count(), max_nbytes=10e6)(delayed(self.solve_one_cochlea, has_shareable_memory)(xx) for xx in self.cochlear_list)

            self.save_model_configuration()
            print("\ncochlear simulation of {} stimulus levels finished in {:0.3f}s".format(len(self.stimulus),                                                                                                timedelta.total_seconds(
                datetime.now() - s1)))
            return results
```

Comment: `joblib` is essentially a convenience  wrapper around `multiprocessing`, so I'm not surprised that you see the same error in both cases. That said, splitting your work into 10,000 individual jobs and dispatching each one separately sounds like a very inefficient way to divide up your task. You'd probably be much better off splitting your work into larger chunks, say 100 or 1000 elements each. You want to do as much as possible in each worker process in order to minimize the relative overhead involved in dispatching the jobs and collecting results.

Comment: That's not what's happening, exactly.   Normally, `cochlear_list` is only 2 or 3 items long.

The problem is, i think, that two of those items are whopping big numpy arrays.  A few gigs each, when dumped as `*.npz` files.

`joblib` promises to solve that by caching to disk and passing by reference, so i'm not copying around massive arrays (see [this](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#working-with-numerical-data-in-shared-memory-memmaping)) , but it's not working as advertised.

Comment: That was my best guess based on incomplete information. It's impossible to know exactly what you're passing to `delayed`, since you haven't defined what `CochleaModel`, `self.irr_on`, `self.solve_one_cochlea` etc are. It would make it a lot easier to debug if you turned this into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), complete with fake input data.

Comment: Also, could you fix your indentation please?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue - @gvoysey were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @snazzili : no, i rearchitected so i wasn't relying on memoization and wasn't passing large arrays directly any more.

Comment: @gvoysey thanks for the update, i appreciate it! For anyone reading this thread and is interested - i used LRU cache to store my dataframe outisde of the multiprocessing code and it ended up working smoothly.